# `nix run .` works, but `nix run github:myorg/myrepo` doesn't

Tags: github, nix, flake

I have a `flake.nix` with an `apps.default` among its outputs.  If I am in the project directory, the app runs when I run:

```
nix run .
```

But when I try to run it from a different machine:

```
nix run github:myorg/myrepo
```

I get the following error

```
error: unable to download 'https://api.github.com/repos/myorg/myrepo/commits/HEAD': HTTP error 404

       response body:

       {
         "message": "Not Found",
         "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/commits/commits#get-a-commit"
       }
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a repo is private, and you are not authenticated, github will respond with a 404.

Making the repo public solved the problem.